# Filtering products query by attribute

Tags: mysql

i have got 3tables in my database. sub_property, sub_property_value and products. now i  plan to write a query for filtering. for example. show me all products which are samsung and their price is less than 400 euro.

[image]

Comment: Nice! Good idea. Thank you for informing us about your plans. If you have a problem with the query, come back with what you have tried so far and post your code.

Comment: show us what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct *
from sub_property_value
INNER join products on  products.product_id=sub_property_value.product_id
INNER join sub_property ON sub_property_value.sub_property_id=sub_property.sub_property_id
INNER join property ON sub_property.property_id=property.property_id
INNER join sub_category ON property.sub_category_id=sub_category.sub_cat_id

where sub_property_value.sub_property_value in ('android','5mega pixel') and sub_category.sub_cat_id in ('1') and sub_property.sub_property_id in ('9','11')
```

Comment: `DISTINCT *` is oxymoronic

Answer (score 0):

In first place you need to specify column names like `SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, c3` for distinct function, can not use it as such.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i remove distinct but still have a problem with that .